# jQuery fix for "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

My code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>      
<script src="http://someothersite.com/external.js"></script>
```

external.js:

```
$("head").append(unescape(""));
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following error when I include my external script:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

How do I fix this? Please bear in mind I can't edit the external Javascript file as it's third party.

Comment: Use 'jQuery' instead of the '$' symbol.

Comment: Are you including jQuery *before* this other include?

Comment: @NickCraver Hi Nick, I'm including jQuery before this call.

Comment: @cgee Could you show me in an Answer and I can green tick if it works :)

Comment: Are you using any CMS or other library overriding `$` reference? Or maybe `jQuery.noConflict()` call

Comment: Make sure you include it before this script is run. Also if you did it, check of typos, whether it is included or not? You can check that in sources tab of any dev tools.

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm using WordPress but the external file is totally separate.

Comment: @AyushGupta Yes. jQuery library is included. And then a call to the external js file happens.

Comment: Is there any piece of code that may have overridden `$`?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk I'm not a wordpress user but http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/441/how-to-link-external-jquery-javascript-files-with-wordpress  If you need it for script loaded later,  i would just use something like: `$(window).on('load', function(){this.$ = jQuery;});` Try it in last resort

Comment: @A.Wolff Many thanks. I will take a look at this right now & get back to you.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk I added `wordpress` tag in question because it is all about it :) Hope more expert about WP would give you correct way of doing it (if still not resolved)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was using an old version of jQuery.

I updated the version and this resolved the issue for me.

Woop!

Comment: If you are working with an older version @WisdmLabs answer will work.

Answer (score 61):

Use the following statement in a JS file.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// jQuery code is in here

});
```

After declaring the above statement you will be able to use $ sign.

Comment: Thanks for this. Does this work when pulling an external JS file in?

Comment: Ya, if OP is using e.g wordpress CMS, that woul be it

Comment: @michaelmcgurk No, but your question is really really missing lot of context, so who knows...

Comment: @A.Wolff I've updated the question to hopefully have more context :)

Comment: On updating Jquery. existing problem solved.

Comment: Thanks, it worked !

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue was because the external javascript was loaded first before the jquery was loaded. To solve this use requirejs, follow this link for the usage http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I don't have direct access to edit the external file itself. How do I work around this?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Just set global reference of `$` pointing to jQuery. But you need first to check why isn't it already the case...

Comment: @A.Wolff Can you possibly show me this in an Answer?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Can you 'possibly' answer any previous questions asked as comment??? SO isn't just a copy/paste code service, show some efforts

Comment: @A.Wolff Can you ''possibly'' point me in the direction of the questions that need answering and I will help do so :)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk You did it behind opening question :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, Neil. I will look to try this shortly and report back. @A.Wolff I'm confused where this is going tbh.

Comment: @Neil I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noConflict' of undefined` when I run that. I obviously run it after jQuery has loaded but before the external js file is loaded.

Comment: If that's the case use jQuery instead of $

Comment: I will update the main question in a minute :-)

Comment: give a reference to $ by `$ = jQuery;`

Comment: If you could just share your html code and the external js

Comment: Thanks, Neil - I have now updated the original question.